# Livewire 3 - Checkbox do not checked

Tags: checkbox, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I am doing a website and I'm on the new version of livewire 3, I am trying to do a checkbox All, but the problem is the value is on my tab but the checkbox dont want to checked:
[Checkbox do not checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZN2u.png)

If someone can help me !

The view:
first checkbox:

[Code of the main checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXiEY.png)

Both other:
[Other's checkbox code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks6ju.png)

Component:

[Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rItFL.png)

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HuOv.png)

We can see the id's on the array, but the checkbox dont check, and i already try to convert int in string but nothing happen:
[When i checked the main checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvvwA.png)
And if i checked the 2 down checkbox:
[When i checked the main and both other's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YjgS.png)

I guess the problem come from when i checked one of the 2 checkbox the function is called but should not.

If i look in the network, I don't see any update about my selected property:
[Network screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxLkm.png)

Comment: try using wire:model.defer

Comment: @SyaifudinZuhri Not working

Comment: try add attribute id on your input.

Comment: Not working... @SyaifudinZuhri

Comment: @Xnern did you endup solving this one? I'm having the same issue after updating to Livewire 3.

Comment: @viniciusalvess yes 2 day ago, I don't really know how, but now with juste this line:
            $this->selected = $this->files->pluck('id');
It work, im using the same property and HTML than my problem before .

Comment: @Xnern Thanks for getting back to me. For me what worked was to change my logic to set the value of the check box with boolean values. On livewire 2 worked with string and boolean values, but on livewire 3 it just works with true or false, not even with 0 and 1.